# Proving ${\Vert * \Vert}_q \le {\Vert * \Vert}_p$ whenever $p\le q$

Tags: normed-spaces

I am trying to prove this:
$${\Vert * \Vert}_q \le {\Vert * \Vert}_p \text{ whenever } p\le q$$
from this question: https://math.stackexchange.com/a/557310/491852

I tried out some examples like $p=1, q=2, \vec x=\begin{bmatrix}1\\2\\3\end{bmatrix}$ and I got $||x||_2=14\le||x||_1=6$ which is a clear counterexample, where am i going wrong?

And if the linked post is wrong then what could one correctly say about $||\cdot||_p$ wrt $||\cdot||_q$?

Comment: You forgot the square root. $\|x\|_2=\sqrt {14}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $x=0$, then we immediately get $\|x\|_q = 0 \leq 0 = \|x\|_p$. So assume $x\neq0$. First, take $x \in \mathbb{R}^n$, such that $\|x\|_p=1$. Then,
$$
1 = \|x\|_p^p = \sum_{i=1}^n|x_i|^p,
$$
hence $0\leq|x_i|\leq1$ for all $i$. Since $p \leq q$, we get
$$
\|x\|_q^q = \sum_{i=1}^n|x_i|^q \leq \sum_{i=1}^n|x_i|^p = \|x\|_p^p = 1,
$$
and hence $\|x\|_q \leq \|x\|_p$.

Next, take an arbitrary $x \in \mathbb{R}^n$ and define $y := x/\|x\|_p$. We have $\|y\|_p=1$, so from what we have just shown, we get
$$
\|y\|_q \leq \|y\|_p \iff \frac{\|x\|_q}{\|x\|_p} \leq \frac{\|x\|_p}{\|x\|_p} \iff \|x\|_q \leq \|x\|_p,
$$
where we used the homogeneity of the norm $\|\cdot\|_p$.

I hope this is helpful!